# Examine the convergence of the following improper integrals.

Tags: improper-integrals, problem-solving

$\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{1-x}}dx,\int_0^1
\frac{\log(1-x)}{\sqrt x}dx$

I am confused how to examine the convergence.I have tried comparison test but it cannot be applied.Can someone provide some help.

Comment: These two integrals are equal simply by consdering the substitution $x \rightarrow 1-x$. Also, $\frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ tends toward $0$ as $x$ approaches $1$ from the left, so the infinite discontinuity located at $x=0$ is what's making this integral improper. Now use the fact that $$0\leq -\frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt{1-x}}\leq -\frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt{1-1/2}}$$ on $(0,1/2]$ to show $\int_0^{1/2}-\frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt{1-x}}dx$ converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment by Matthew Pilling, these integrals are equivalent.  There are singularities at both ends.  I will work on$\int\limits_0^1\frac{log(1-x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx$  Near $x=0$, $log(1-x) \approx -x$, so the integrand $\approx -\sqrt{x}$ and is O.K.  At $x\approx 1$, the integrand $\approx log(1-x)$ with integral$\approx (x-1)(log(1-x)-1)$ which is finite.